# Is it reasonable to make an analogy between conjugate gradients and conjugate diameters of an ellipse?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

Section 8.6.2 of ["Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. Deep Learning"](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) uses the term "conjugate directions" without any further explanation.

> Conjugate gradients is a method to efficiently avoid the calculation of the inverse
>   Hessian by iteratively descending conjugate directions. The inspiration for this
>   approach follows from a careful study of the weakness of the method of steepest
>   descent ...

this [post](http://www.pha.jhu.edu/~neufeld/numerical/lecturenotes8.pdf) gives this definition

> Thus the optimum direction is not along –∇f,
>   but rather in a direction that preserves the
>   minimization achieved in the previous step
>   (and, in multi-dimensions, all previous steps)
>
> This is called the conjugate direction

to get more intuitive understanding of this concept, I am trying to make an analogy between conjugate gradients and [conjugate diameters of an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_diameters#Of_ellipse), is it reasonable?